# PHP function not passing data to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I've setup a sign up page to register users, its passed from HTML and into PHP 
however the PHP function is not passing it over to the MySQL database

```
   <?php
     try{
      $db = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=car_rental;port=3306","root","");

    }
    catch (Exception $e){
      echo "SQL is Off";
      exit;

    }
    echo "success"; 

    try{
    $trial = "INSERT INTO users (firstName) VALUES ('trial')";

    }
    catch (Exception $e){
      echo "doesnt work..";
    }
    echo "works?";
     try{
     function NewUser() 
     { 
       $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
       $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
       $age = $_POST['age'];
       $email = $_POST['email']; 
      $password = $_POST['pass']; 
      $query = "INSERT INTO users (firstName,lastName,age,email,pass) VALUES ('$firstName','$lastName','$age','$email','$password')";
      echo"user created";
      }
     }
     catch (PDOException $e)
     {
       echo "ERROR -_-";
     }

      ?>
```

is this the correct implementation to execute a sql query in PHP?

```
function NewUser() 
 { 
   $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
   $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
   $age = $_POST['age'];
   $email = $_POST['email']; 
  $password = $_POST['pass']; 
  $query = "INSERT INTO users (firstName,lastName,age,email,pass) VALUES ('$firstName','$lastName','$age','$email','$password')";
  $db->exec($query);
  echo"user created";
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: You just write queries, but forgot to execute

Comment: where is query function??

Comment: Where is your sql query executing?

Comment: Hey, just  heads up, this is extremely insecure! You are not sanitizing any of your input, and so people could pass malicious code and run it on your database with an SQL injection. If this is just to learn then you might not care, but if this is going online, you need to fix that. Also, you are saving passwords in plain text, which is very bad, but again, fine if you are just playing around with learning how to call a database from php. I just wanted to mention all that incase this is for anything real.

Comment: its just to learn so no need to worry but i will keep it in mind if ever i upload it @rp.beltran

Comment: Ok, no worries then, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just write queries, but forgot to execute

```
$db = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=car_rental;port=3306","root","");
$query = "INSERT INTO users (firstName,lastName,age,email,pass) VALUES ('$firstName','$lastName','$age','$email','$password')";
$db->query($db); // executes it
```

Comment: so it basically becomes   $db = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=car_rental;port=3306","root","");



 
 function NewUser() 
 { 
   $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
   $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
   $age = $_POST['age'];
   $email = $_POST['email']; 
  $password = $_POST['pass']; 
  $query = "INSERT INTO users (firstName,lastName,age,email,pass) VALUES ('$firstName','$lastName','$age','$email','$password')";
  $db->query($db);
  echo"user created";
  }